# URL encoding to Hex while returning JSON

Tags: java, json

The below code is written on JAVA servlet with
          response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); , but it is giving hex while we try it from the browser. I want it to return the plain url , that is in the code. Pleaes help.

```
      Map addetials = new HashMap();
        addetials.put("id", "1");
             addetials.put("ur", "https://ad?url=[referrer_url]&description_url=[description_url]&correlator=[timestamp]");

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        out.print(gson.toJson(addetials.toString()));
```

Response :

```
  "{blockKey\u003d, ur\u003dhttps%3A%2F%2FstartBreferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D%5Btimestamp%5D, id\u003d1}"
```

Comment: java.net.URLDecoder.decode(your url, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this..

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();